# Using YUP with Material-UI TextField

Tags: material-ui, rect, formik, yup

I'm trying to convert a form to use Material-ui TextField. How do I get my YUP validation to work with that? Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";

import Error from "../../Error";

type FormValues = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  repeatPassword: string;
  fullName: string;
  country: string;
  email: string;
};

export default function CreatePrivateUserForm(props: any) {

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState();

  const createPrivateAccountSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string()
      .required("Required")
      .min(8, "Too Short!")
      .max(20, "Too Long!")
      .matches(/^[\w-.@ ]+$/, {
        message: "Inccorect carector"
      }),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("Required")
      .min(10, "Too Short!")
      .max(100, "Too Long!")
      .matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]).*$/, {
        message: "Password need to contain 1 uppercase character (A-Z), 1 lowercase character (a-z), 1 digit (0-9) and 1 special character (punctuation)"
      }),
    repeatPassword: Yup.string()
      .required("Required")
      .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Passwords must match")
  });



  function handleSuccess() {
    alert("User was created");
  }

  async function handleSubmit(values: FormValues) {
    const token = await props.googleReCaptchaProps.executeRecaptcha("CreatePrivateUser");

    const headers = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        recaptcha: token
      }
    };

    const body = { username: values.username, password: values.password, repeatPassword: values.repeatPassword };

    const url = "xxx";

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(url, body, headers);
      if (response.status === 201) {
        handleSuccess();
      }
      if (response.status === 400) {
        console.log("Bad Request ...");
        setErrorMessage('Bad Request');
      } else if (response.status === 409) {
        console.log("Conflict ...");
        setErrorMessage('Conflict');
      } else if (response.status === 422) {
        console.log("Client Error ...");
        setErrorMessage('Client Error');
      } else if (response.status > 422) {
        console.log("Something went wrong ...");
        setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
      } else {
        console.log("Server Error ...");
        setErrorMessage('Server Error');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Fejl");
    }
  }



  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12}>
          <p>Please register by entering the required information.</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ username: "", password: "", repeatPassword: "" }}
            validationSchema={createPrivateAccountSchema}
            onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
              await handleSubmit(values);
              setSubmitting(false);
            }}>
            {({ isSubmitting }) => (
              <Form>
                {errorMessage ? <Error errorMessage={errorMessage} /> : null}
                <Row>
                  <Col xs={6}>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={12}>
                        <TextField
                          label="Username"
                          helperText={touched.username ? errors.username : ""}
                          error={touched.username && Boolean(errors.username)}
                          type="text"
                          name="username"
                          margin="normal"
                          variant="filled"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage name='username'>{msg => <div className='error'>{msg}</div>}</ErrorMessage>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={12}>
                        <label htmlFor='password'>Password:</label>
                        <Field type='password' name='password' />
                        <ErrorMessage name='password'>{msg => <div className='error'>{msg}</div>}</ErrorMessage>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={12}>
                        <label htmlFor='repeatPassword'>Repeat password:</label>
                        <Field type='password' name='repeatPassword' />
                        <ErrorMessage name='repeatPassword'>{msg => <div className='error'>{msg}</div>}</ErrorMessage>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs={12}>
                    <button type='submit' disabled={isSubmitting}>
                      Create User
                      </button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I can see is that you have stripped out the standard formik `<Field />` components and directly changed to `<TextField />`. The `<Field />` component is actually a special component that "will automagically hook up inputs to Formik. It uses the name attribute to match up with Formik state" according to the fomik documentation. As a result I believe that formik is no longer actually handling the inputs and instead these are uncontrolled components (html components without a value set by react state). With formik no-longer handling the inputs the Yup validation build into formik and being used via the schema prop won't function correctly.

To solve this issue you can either use a libary (material UI suggests this libary - https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui) or you can make custom input components for formik. This allows you to set the `<Field />`'s component prop to a component that correctly wires up material UI with the formik data `<Field />` exposes.

```
const CustomTextInput = ({
    field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
    form: { touched, errors }, // also values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, etc.
    ...props
}) => (
    <div>
        <TextField
            error={_.get(touched, field.name) && _.get(errors, field.name) && true}
            helperText={_.get(touched, field.name) && _.get(errors, field.name)}
            {...field}
            {...props}
        />
    </div>
)
```

Then in your form you can do this

```
<Field
    name="fieldName"
    component={CustomTextInput}
    label="You can use the Material UI props here to adjust the input"
/>
```

You can find an example and more information about this on the formik documentation on field - https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field