# validate hour field with yup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup

I have field hour declared in material-ui **TextField**. I want to add **Yup validation** to control the format for the value typed which should respect this format: *02:30*

How can I control it with **Yup**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using YUP with Material-UI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008018/using-yup-with-material-ui-textfield)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to achieve your goal.
I made in this way:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  hour: yup
    .string()
    .length(5)
    .matches(/(\d){2}:(\d){2}/, 'Hour must have this pattern "00:00"'),
});
```